# Cine available method in kvmd to print a hard copy of a PNG file in Android

Tags: python, android, kivymd

I for lack of knowledge I could not find any solution of this if any kind hearted person can help me I will be thankful for this previously I use jnius autoclass but when I complile the py file to APK then I get some error and I can't solve it

If anyone have any solution how to print a PNG file through a printer using kivymd app on Android then please help me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.